What does "admissible" actually mean in the theory of classic Strichartz estimates for Schrodinger equations?
I only know that in the theory of classic Strichartz estimates for Schrodinger equations, the concept "admissible pair" can be explained by considering scaling-invariance of the inequality
$\|e^{-it\Delta}u_0\|_{L_t^qL_x^r}\leq C\|u_0\|_{L_x^2}$. I wonder is there other explanation for this admissibility of pairs of exponents? The reason why I ask this is that in the problems of space-fractional Schrodinger equations, Strichartz estimates are usually stated in terms of Sobolev spaces or Besov spaces, but it is known that no scaling argument can be performed in the framework of these two spaces. So, there is no way to verify whether the classic definition of admissibility makes senses in the space-fractional problems through the scaling-invariance explanation.
